# Win10 kali dual boot installing problem

Tags: kali-linux, uefi

I prepared a Bootable kali 2016 USB using win32diskimager, like the tutorial on kali's official site. I restarted the computer, and boot from my kali USB, but the setup doesn't start, after a while my pc boot from hard disk normally . I tried an Ubuntu İSO, it booted and started Ubuntu installation. So I thought that problem is about kali İSO, so I compared Ubuntu and kali İSO.  I saw while Ubuntu include an **efi** file, there is no **efi ** file on kali. Is problem about no including this file, and how to solve this? Thanks

Comment: Did you try 64-bit image, and does Kali Linux declare UEFI support at all? (I've implemented that in ALT Linux and could probably share [some advice](https://en.altlinux.org/UEFI_SecureBoot_mini-HOWTO) but that's a chunk of work)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was the secure boot is enabled, I disabled and tried again, it worked and got installing screen [SOLVED]

Answer (score 0):

yes for dual booting any OS with the PC/Laptop which comes with windows 10 need to be disabled secure boot and enable legacy mode. 
source: http://www.techyguide.net/dual-boot-kali-linux-windows-10/